# Indesign scripting: How to add color to the dialog staticTexts

Tags: javascript, dom-events, adobe-indesign

Currently developing a script for Indesign CS6, using JavaScript. I am looking for a way to add color to the labels in a dialog UI. The sample code is as follows:

```
var myDialog = app.dialogs.add({name:"User Interface Example Script", canCancel:true});
with(myDialog){
    //Add a dialog column.
    with(dialogColumns.add()){
        //Create a border panel.
        
        with(borderPanels.add()){
        
            with(dialogColumns.add()){
                //The following line shows how to set a property as you create an object.
                staticTexts.add({staticLabel:"Message:"});
```

I wonder how you can make that label Message a custom color.

I've found a partial solution using other classes from the JavaScript API however I would still like to know if the above is possible.

```
 var w = new Window("dialog");
var s = w.add ("statictext", undefined, "Static");
var e = w.add ("edittext", undefined, "Edit");
var b = w.add ("button", undefined, "Button");

// The window's backround
w.graphics.backgroundColor = w.graphics.newBrush (w.graphics.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR, [0.5, 0.0, 0.0]);
// Font and its colour for the first item, statictext
s.graphics.font = ScriptUI.newFont ("Helvetica", "Bold", 30);
s.graphics.foregroundColor = s.graphics.newPen (w.graphics.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [0.7, 0.7, 0.7], 1);
// Font and colours for the second item, edittext
e.graphics.font = ScriptUI.newFont ("Letter Gothic Std", "Bold", 30);
e.graphics.foregroundColor = e.graphics.newPen (e.graphics.PenType.SOLID_COLOR, [1, 0, 0], 1);
e.graphics.backgroundColor = e.graphics.newBrush (e.graphics.BrushType.SOLID_COLOR, [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]);
// Font for the tird control, a button. Can't set colours in buttons
b.graphics.font = ScriptUI.newFont ("Minion Pro", "Italic", 30);
w.show ();
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible just with javascript. You might want to look into some of the other solutions that Adobe offers for making UI's.

Comment: @JoshVoigts sorry this is incorrect, It is possible and its very flexible, I'll edit my question with some code that partially accomplishes what I am looking for.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected, I guess you learn something new every day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [API](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5/inxx.html), there are two separate classes for static text (`StaticText (SUI)` and `StaticText`). It looks like the first class [StaticText (SUI)](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5/pc_StaticText%20%28SUI%29.html) offers the ability to color static text whereas the second [StaticText](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs5/pc_StaticText.html) does not.

In your question, the first code snippet you show is using the `StaticText` class, so graphic options (colors) aren't available to it. The second code sample is using the `StaticText (SUI)` class, that's why you're able to color it.

I found a nice overview, that you might be interested in, of the difference between the UI APIs [here](http://forums.adobe.com/docs/DOC-1025).

So, to answer your question, in order to add color to the dialog you would have to create your own dialog using a window and the Scripting UI classes (SUI) instead of using the "built in" dialog class.